# ALSA linking when cross-compiling Rust program for ARM

Tags: docker, rust, arm, raspbian, alsa

I'm trying to cross-compile a simple Rust program to record sound with ALSA drivers on a Raspberry Pi Zero using the [wavy crate](https://crates.io/crates/wavy) inside a Docker container that has the `libasound-dev` library installed. However, the linker complains about:

```
 note: /opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8.3/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that Cargo is asking rustc to link against the asound lib dynamically with the argument `-Bdynamic" "-lasound"`. How do I tell Cargo where to look for these ALSA libraries?

**Update:** I added the following to my Cargo.toml file and added `--features "alsa-backend"` to my `cargo build` command which seems to have progressed the build:

```
[features]
alsa-backend = ["alsa"]

[dependencies]
alsa            = { version = "0.2.1", optional = true }
```

It now throws:

```
note: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

OK, so it's linking against the x86_64 version of libasound.so. I typed `dpkg -L libasound-dev` in my Docker container and indeed, it lists `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so` instead of an ARM version.

How do I tell the Raspbian Docker container to link against the ARM version of `libasound.so`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

1. Install the armhf version of libasound-dev to your Raspbian docker image:

```
apt-get install libasound-dev -y
apt-get install libasound-dev:armhf -y
```

(If you only install `libasound-dev:armhf`, it will complain about `alsa-sys` linker errors.)

2. Add `alsa` dependency to Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
alsa = { version = "0.2.1", optional = true }
wavy = { path = "./wavy" }
```

3. Set `alsa-backend` flag in Cargo.toml:

```
[features]
alsa-backend = ["alsa"]
```

4. Pass `--features "alsa-backend"` to `cargo build --target arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` (target should be applied)
5. Tell rustc to use the armhf version in `.cargo/config`:

```
[build]

[target.arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf.libasound]
linker = "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
rustc-link-lib = ["libasound"]
rustc-link-search = ["/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf"]
```

(Depending on the order it links, it may try to use the x86 version instead of the armhf version.)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution!