# Cross compiling alsa crate for armv7

Tags: rust, arm, cross-compiling, alsa

I'm trying to cross-compile for `amrv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` a rust binary based on the [alsa](https://crates.io/crates/alsa) crate.

For the cross-compilation, I'm using [Cross](https://crates.io/crates/cross) with a custom Dockerfile to have the required dependencies:

```
FROM ghcr.io/cross-rs/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf:0.2.5

RUN dpkg --add-architecture armhf && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libasound2-dev:armhf \
        libudev-dev:armhf \
        pkg-config:armhf

RUN apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY .cargo/config.toml /root/.cargo/config.toml
```

I followed the instruction from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037550/alsa-linking-when-cross-compiling-rust-program-for-arm) about cross compiling for arm, by adding the following `.cargo/config.toml` file:

```
[build]

[target.arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf.libasound]
linker = "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
rustc-link-lib = ["libasound"]
rustc-link-search = ["/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf"]
```

But this leads to the following error, with `pkg-config` complaining about not finding the alsa library:

```
➜  alsa-cross git:(master) ✗ cross build --target armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --features "alsa-backend" -v
+ cargo metadata --format-version 1 --filter-platform armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --features alsa-backend
+ rustc --print sysroot
+ rustup toolchain list
+ rustup target list --toolchain stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
+ rustup component list --toolchain stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
+ /usr/bin/docker
+ "/gitrepos/alsa-cross" /usr/bin/docker build --label 'org.cross-rs.for-cross-target=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf' --label 'org.cross-rs.workspace_root=/gitrepos/alsa-cross' --tag cross-custom-alsa-cross:armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-7235a --build-arg 'CROSS_DEB_ARCH=armhf' --build-arg 'CROSS_BASE_IMAGE=ghcr.io/cross-rs/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf:0.2.5' --file ./Dockerfile /gitrepos/alsa-cross
Sending build context to Docker daemon  30.33MB
Step 1/6 : FROM ghcr.io/cross-rs/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf:0.2.5
 ---> 32cf786140f9
Step 2/6 : RUN dpkg --add-architecture armhf &&     apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends         libasound2-dev:armhf         libudev-dev:armhf         pkg-config:armhf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8288951e6f23
Step 3/6 : RUN apt-get autoremove -y &&     apt-get clean &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e0ba37616482
Step 4/6 : COPY .cargo/config.toml /root/.cargo/config.toml
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 68d32d3aa8f2
Step 5/6 : LABEL org.cross-rs.for-cross-target=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 42924a9ff180
Step 6/6 : LABEL org.cross-rs.workspace_root=/gitrepos/alsa-cross
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 98094b203092
[Warning] One or more build-args [CROSS_DEB_ARCH CROSS_BASE_IMAGE] were not consumed
Successfully built 98094b203092
Successfully tagged cross-custom-alsa-cross:armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-7235a
+ /usr/bin/docker run --userns host -e 'PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1' -e 'XARGO_HOME=/xargo' -e 'CARGO_HOME=/cargo' -e 'CARGO_TARGET_DIR=/target' -e 'CROSS_RUNNER=' -e TERM -e 'USER=florian' --rm --user 1000:1000 -v /home/florian/.xargo:/xargo:z -v /home/florian/.cargo:/cargo:z -v /cargo/bin -v /gitrepos/alsa-cross:/project:z -v /home/florian/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu:/rust:z,ro -v /gitrepos/alsa-cross/target:/target:z -w /project -i -t cross-custom-alsa-cross:armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-7235a sh -c 'PATH=$PATH:/rust/bin cargo build --target armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf --features alsa-backend -v'
       Fresh pkg-config v0.3.27
       Fresh libc v0.2.145
       Fresh bitflags v1.3.2
       Fresh cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling alsa-sys v0.3.1
       Fresh nix v0.24.3
     Running `/target/debug/build/alsa-sys-5b7e484eb5de5d94/build-script-build`
error: failed to run custom build command for `alsa-sys v0.3.1`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/target/debug/build/alsa-sys-5b7e484eb5de5d94/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ALSA_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ALSA_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=ALSA_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '`PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS="1" PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS="1" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/:" "pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "alsa"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 2
  error: could not find system library 'alsa' required by the 'alsa-sys' crate

  --- stderr
  /usr/bin/pkg-config: 1: /usr/bin/pkg-config: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
  ', /cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/alsa-sys-0.3.1/build.rs:13:18
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
+ rustup component list --toolchain stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Do you have any lead about how to fix this error ?

I have tried the following:

1. Adding the feature flag "alsa-backend" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037550/alsa-linking-when-cross-compiling-rust-program-for-arm)
2. Custom `.cargo/config.toml` as described in the same post
3. Look at all the stackoverflow posts related to cross compiling alsa to armv7, but I didn't find any useful responses, when the post had responses at all.

Comment: I tackled a **very** similar problem a while ago, and I didn't get it to work with `cross`. I did, however, get it to work with `cargo` directly: https://github.com/Finomnis/librespot-docker Maybe the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Finomnis/librespot-docker/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile) in it helps you in your situation.

Comment: Nitpick: Don't run `apt-get install` and the respective cleanup commands in two separate `RUN` commands. That defeats the entire purpose of the cleanup. They **have** to be in the same `RUN`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your Dockerfile Finomnis ! I was able to put the following [Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/N9aK5R3j) together from yours. But do you know how I could change it to retrieve the binaries/libraries ? And to cache the previous build results. I think I should remove the last few lines and build the docker once, then run "docker run" commands to do the actual building ?

Comment: I added an answer that goes through it step-by-step, I hope this helps

Comment: Heads up: I only tested it with a `cargo new` project, without any actual need for `libasound`. Please test if it works with an actual `alsa` project and then give me some feedback whether the answer works for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a way with `cross`, but I personally didn't manage to achieve it.

I did, however, achieve this by using the cross-building functionality of cargo directly.

Create the following `Dockerfile`:

```bash
ARG DEBIAN_VERSION="11.7"

FROM debian:${DEBIAN_VERSION}

# Install target compilation targets
RUN dpkg --add-architecture armhf

# Add cross compilers and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --yes \
    curl git crossbuild-essential-armhf pkg-config \
    libasound2-dev:armhf \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install Rust system-wide
ENV RUSTUP_HOME=/opt/rust
ENV CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust
ENV CARGO_REGISTRIES_CRATES_IO_PROTOCOL=sparse
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y --no-modify-path
ENV PATH="/opt/rust/bin:${PATH}"

# Add cross compilation target and set as default
RUN rustup target add armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
ENV CARGO_BUILD_TARGET=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf

# Configure Rust linkers for cross compilation
ENV CARGO_TARGET_ARMV7_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABIHF_LINKER=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc

# Configure pkg-config for cross compilation
ENV PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1/
ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/

# Set the working directory to /src, where we will mount our project
WORKDIR /src
```

Build the docker container (I named it `armv7_cross` here):

```bash
docker build -t armv7_cross .
```

Then, inside of your project directory, you can do:

```bash
docker run -v $PWD:/src --user $(id -u):$(id -g) --rm -ti armv7_cross cargo build
```

This should build like normally, and you should get our output at `target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`.

Explanation of the `docker run` flags:

- `-v $PWD:/src` - Mounts the current directory to `/src` in your docker container
- `--user $(id -u):$(id -g)` - Configures user and group id, otherwise all your build outputs would be owned by `root`
- `--rm` - Destroys the docker container again after building
- `-ti` - Interactive terminal mode, to get some pretty colors
- `armv7_cross` - The name of the docker image
- `cargo build` - The command that gets executed inside of the container.

  Note we already set `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` as the default target inside our docker container, so we don't need to supply a `--target` flag.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. There only seem to be one issue regarding permissions: the cargo build command raises a permission error when cargo tries to write to `/opt/rust` (which makes sens as it was created by root during the build part, and the cargo build is executed with my user and group, 1000:1000). Should I `chmod` the `/opt/rust` folder in the Dockerfile ?

Comment: I'd rather `chown` it instead. But sure, go for it.

Comment: Also note that there isn't really any need for docker here; you could perform the same steps on your host system. Although it's of course always preferrable for reproducibility.